Bit fields and initializer list: Compiler bug or conforming behavior?
In Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.8.6, I'm getting an unexpected warning, and unexpected behavior, when initializing a bit field structure.  Here's the sample program:
#include <iostream>

struct Key
{
    bool complex : 1;
    bool fwd : 1;
    bool inplace : 1;
    int align1 : 5;
    int align2 : 5;
    int size : 32;
};


int main()
{
    {
        // No warning here
        Key k{ (bool) true, (bool)true, (int)false, (int)8, (int)8, (int)512 };

        // This also gives the same behavior
        // Key k{ true, true, false, 8, 8, 512 };

        // k.size is 512 here, correct.
        std::cout << k.size << std::endl;
    }
    {
        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;
        bool c = false;
        int d = 8;
        int e = 8;
        int f = 512;
        // Gives warning, (32,34): warning C4293: '<<': shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
        // That warning is at the 'f' in the line below
        Key k{ a, b, c, d, e, f };

        // k.size is 0 here
        std::cout << k.size << std::endl;
    }
}

The first initializer works as I would expect.  The second initializer says gives a warning that I've invoked UB and then initializes "incorrectly".  (MSVC Version 17.4.1 also gives the warning but then initializes the structure correctly.)  I'm compiling this as C++.  The version of the standard doesn't seem to matter.
This looks to me like a compiler bug.  However, I wonder if there is something else going on here with an initializer list and r-value references and it is in fact UB?

I think you've found a bona fide bug.  Congratulations!  Please report it to Microsoft.  (I used to work at Microsoft on Visual Studio.  If I still worked there, I'd chase this down myself.  Good find!)

gcc and clang accept your program and it works as you would expect. MSVC however fails to compile it.
https://godbolt.org/z/6c3nMc1zb

@Joel You've got /WX on for Visual studio which turns warnings into errors.

@RobL I've got -Werror for gcc and clang as well, which does basically the same. Yes, you could compile the code with warnings, but then you would have UB (according to msvc) and get a warning and IMHO you should not ignore warnings. Especially not if ignoring the warning lets your code produce unexpected results.

There is another possible surprise. The bitfields add up to less than 64 bits in total but the structure actually spans 12 bytes (for both MSC 17.x compiler and Intel 2023). In both cases compiler dependent behaviour starts a new int rather than a new byte when something doesn't fit (or in the case of  int align1 : 5 even when it does! Changing the declaration of align1/2 to char will fix this. I presume that Key was meant to fit into a 64 bit integer.

Thanks folks. I appreciate confirmation that this isn't a purposeful c++ initiailizer list weirdness.  I reported it:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Bit-fields-and-initializer-list-dont-al/10630180?

The report has been marked as duplicate and Fixed - Pending Release:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-codegen-for-aggregate-bitfield/10548205
